# sql statement for two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make sql query between two columns.

table_1

```
ID     ProductName      ProductDescription
1      Prod_1             Description_1
2      Prod_2             Description_1
3      Prod_3             Description_1
4      Prod_4             Description_1
5      Prod_5             Description_1
```

table_2

```
ID       Product       Partner
1          1              21
2          2              21
3          3              21
4          1              32          
5          1              32              
6          4              21              
7          5              21
8          5              32
```

By using query below I get as a result only list of products that are selected in table_2. That is good I need to get that, but I also want to print all values from table_1 in same query for later programming I need that. Not sure is it possible to make one column that will print 1 if product_ID and ID match and if not print 0

```
$query = "SELECT a.ID, a.ProductName, b.ID, b.Product, b.Partner
FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b
ON a.ID = b.Product
WHERE b.Partner = 21"
```

I want to print values from table_1 match with table_2 what are selected in table_2. 
I am getting stuck here any advice is appreciated.

Comment: please post expected result also

Comment: I'm getting stuck here too, but that wouldn't have happened had you also posted your expected output.

Comment: I think it should be a.ID = b.Product . Probably

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i am right with your requirenments this untested query should work:

```
$query = "SELECT a.ID, a.ProductName, b.ID, b.Product, b.Partnerm, case when b.id is null then 0 else 1 end
FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b
ON a.ID = b.ID and b.Partner = 21"
```

Comment: @user3651819 sorry forgot a comma in front of case. Have added it. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT a.ID, a.ProductName, b.ID, b.Product, b.Partnerm case when b.id is null then 0 else 1 end
    FROM table_1 a
    LEFT JOIN table_2 b
    ON a.ID = b.Product and b.Partner = 21"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT a.ID, a.ProductName, b.ID, b.Product, b.Partner FROM table_1 a LEFT JOIN table_2 b
ON a.ID = b.Product WHERE b.Partner = 21"
```

Kinda like this since the connection between table 1 and table 2 is the ID and the product.

Comment: That's not an answer. It does not give right solution. But you are right I made mistake, it shluld be b.Partner but still not correct

Comment: Now I'm confused xD ... Would be easier if you were to provide an sqlfiddle though.

Comment: ohh yeah I saw that. Congrats xD